# NodeJS TCP Server Does Not Receive Data

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, response

I'm trying to create a simple receive-only socket server, in nodejs v0.12.0, to receive messages via TCP. It seems that no data is received unless the nodejs net server response with a line feed after each data event.

```
var server = net.createServer(function( socket ) {
    socket
        .setEncoding( 'utf8' )
        .on( 'data', function( cData ) {
            console.log( 'cData' );
            console.log( cData );

            // Uncomment this to receive data.
            //socket.write( '\n' );
        });

        // Uncomment this to receive data.
        //socket.write( '\n' );
}).listen( 84, '127.0.0.1' );
```

Then the client does this...

```
setInterval( function(){
    client.write( 'test\n' );
}, 1000 );
```

Unless I send a line feed when the client connects and a line feed with each data event, no further data events are triggered. Am I missing something? Do I have to reply with some sort of message with each data event, or is there an option to just receive data without sending a response?

Comment: Everything looks good. Did you call `server.listen(portNo)` ?

Comment: Yes. I've updated my example. It seems when the client connects to the server you must send some server message to the client in order to receive the first client message. Each client message received must be followed by a server message back to the client in order to receive subsequent data events.

Comment: I think the reason nobody is answering is because this is perfectly functional code. From what you provided, there is no reason for that behavior. Have you tried running exactly what you've pasted here (plus the client declaration), with nothing else?

Comment: You're completely right. Testing this code on my end worked. I've left out that, in the original code, I set the port to 110 (POP3) in Windows and for some reason, this is the cause. If I change the port to 84, or just about any other number, it works fine. I've since tested it on a linux machine and another Windows machine and it works fine. I'm guessing it's the Symantec Endpoint Protection that somehow jumping in between the nodejs server and client. I'm going to remove it, and test again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test confirmed. The problem was that my original tests on my machine were using port 110 not 84. Once I disabled Symantec Endpoint Protection from starting up, my tests worked just fine. The protection program must create a proxy between client and server, even on local connections, and act as a relay. This is why the line feed "\n" became such a magical character. The proxy relay created by Symantec on my machine was expecting a POP3 protocol.

Thanks for saving my sanity Luke!

Answer (score 0):

you can changed 127.0.0.1 to your ip address public, in section listen in your code. its working for me